# fit_transform(X) vs fit_transform(X,y)

Tags: python

I am using minmax scaler to scaling X, y data. I saw some people just scaling X and y separately like below:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc=MinMaxScaler()
X=dataset.iloc[:,0:13]
y=dataset.iloc[:,13].values
Xnorm=pd.DataFrame(data=sc.fit_transform(X))
yshape=pd.DataFrame(data=y.reshape(-1,1))
ynorm=pd.DataFrame(data=sc.fit_transform(yshape))

Xnorm.shape
(506, 13)
```

I am wondering if I can scaling both x and y at the same time like below

```
datanorm=pd.DataFrame(data=sc.fit_transform(X,y))
datanorm.shape
(506, 13)
```

However the datanorm is exactly the same as ynorm with 13 columns. I am expecting datanorm should have 14 columns including 13 column from x and one column from y. Am I understanding it correctly?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Generally it's a good to practice to scale/normalize data. Customary X is used to denote training data. Whereas y is used to denote output labels. And there is no need to normalize/scale the labels. Hope you understand it.

Comment: Yeah, but if output y is also a continuous variable, sometimes it is also a good practice to scale y. Anyway fit_transfirm() do have  input of (X,y) in additional to (X) only. It seems to me fit_transfirm(X,y) has exact same result as fit_transform(X). Am I correct? Can anyone confirm it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because in some algorithms, we need to normalize/scale features (X), not label (y). Therefore why do not apply to label?

Thinking again the following steps in ML.
Firstly, we choose a model to work with training data.
Secondly, training the data to find out the best parameters with this data.
Thirdly, we use that estimator to predict(infer) the output(label) from test features(X_test example).

So if you normalize/scale the label, your model (parameters in second step) only work well to normalized/scaled label. The inference value in third step will be low score.